# Best way to replace middle element of array (dynamic) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am still pretty new to programing and have been working on challenges. One of them is creating a function that will:

-> Change the middle value in an odd array to a string "Hi"
-> Return an even array as it is (no changes)

I have managed to find the middle element in the array with no problem (also setting up the condition for even arrays).

But I am struggling to figure out how to actually replace the element with a string and return the array.

For example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 'hi", 4, 5]

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thank you all for your help

```
function hiInTheMiddle(arry) {
  if(arry.length % 2 === 0) {
    return arry
  }
  let middle = arry[Math.floor((arry.length - 1) / 2)];
}
```

Comment: The same way you set any array element.

Comment: You are almost there. Instead of assigning the current element to `middle`, simply turn it around and assign the new value to the element! (So instead of `let middle = stuff` you have `stuff = 'hi'`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this requirement by just finding the `index` of middle element and then assign the `hi` string to that index.

Live Demo **:**

```js
function hiInTheMiddle(arry) {
  if(arry.length % 2 === 0) {
    return arry;
  }
  arry[Math.floor((arry.length - 1) / 2)] = 'hi';
  return arry;
}

const res = hiInTheMiddle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer. Hope it will work as per the expectation now.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the middle element with `arr[middle] = 'Hi'`

So the code you need should be something like this:

```js
let evenArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let oddArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
// defined test arrays

function hiInTheMiddle(arr) {
  if (arr.length % 2 === 0) {
    return arr;
  }
  
  arr[arr.length / 2 - 0.5] = 'Hi';
  return arr;
}

console.log(hiInTheMiddle(evenArr), hiInTheMiddle(oddArr));
// test the code
```

Answer (score 0):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const odd = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const even = [1, 2, 3, 4];

/**
 * If array has an odd numbered .length, replace the middle item of array 
 * with a given string.
 * @param {Array} arr  - An array of unknown values
 * @param {String} str - A string to insert into the array. 
 * @return {Array} - If undefined it returns @default as "|". 
 *         If arr .length is even, the array is returned untouched.
 */
const mid = (arr, str = "|") => {
  // If arr is odd...
  if (arr.length % 2 === 1) {
    // replace the middle item with the given string
    arr.splice((arr.length / 2), 1, str);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(mid(odd)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(mid(even)))
```